# How can I save the metadata of the user_function in curry?

Tags: python, function, metadata, currying, functools

I have this code:

```
def curry_explicit(function, arity):
    """
    Turning a function from several parameters into a function from one parameter that returns a function from the other parameters:
    function(a,b) --> function(a)(b)
    """
    if arity == 0:
        return function

    def get_args(args):
        if len(args) == arity:
            return function(*args)

        def curry(x):
            return get_args([*args, x])

        return curry

    return get_args([])


user_function = max

curried_function = curry_explicit(user_function, 3)

print(curried_function.__name__)
```

```
curry
```

I need the name curried_function to match the name of the function that we curried:

```
print(curried_function.__name__)
```

```
max
```

Maybe i can use functools wraps? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do:

```
def curry_explicit(function, arity):
    """
    Turning a function from several parameters into a function from one parameter that returns a function from the other parameters:
    function(a,b) --> function(a)(b)
    """
    if arity == 0:
        return function

    def get_args(args):
        if len(args) == arity:
            return function(*args)

        def curry(x):
            func = get_args([*args, x])
            return func

        curry.__name__ = function.__name__
        return curry

    return get_args([])
```

But honestly not sure if there are consequences to doing this. The functools library probably has a good solution (likely using the `@wraps` decorator as you suggested or something similar).